# bash pattern matching operator ## does not work in script

Tags: bash

Following one example of the book << Learning the Bash Shell >> (O'Reilly),

```
pathname="/home/cam/book/long.file.name"
echo ${pathname##/*/}
echo ${pathname#/*/}
```

The expected result should be `long.file.name`, since `##` remove the longest prefix which matches the patter `/*/`.

However, when I put these three lines inside a script file and run it inside bash, there is no result displayed. But type in these two lines one by one works and shows the expected result.

I wonder if there is any setting related to usage of this operator `##` inside executable script.

(Using ubuntu\trusty64 within vagrant.)

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

The code works fine, the other part of the code affects the results.

**In Addition**

`${path##*/}` is a better choice as equivalent to `basename` command.

Comment: Works fine for me.  Try running `bash -x scriptname` and then [edit] your question and copy-and-paste the results as an update to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Though `echo ${pathname##/*/}` works fine for me but IMHO you should try following.

```
echo ${pathname##*/}
```

Which means you are saying bash with help of regex to remove/substitute everything from starting till last occurrence of `/` with NULL.